# Python Pandas: difference of column values insert into new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 
p1 q1 r1 20  
p2 q2 r2 10  
p3 q3 r1 30
```

The Desired output looks like this.

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 NewColumn(c1.1)
p1 q1 r1 20  0
p2 q2 r2 10  p2-p1
p3 q3 r1 30  p3-p2
```

The shape of my dataset is(333650,665) I want to do that for all columns. Are there any ways to achieve this?

The code I am using:

```
data = pd.read_csv('Mydataset.csv')
    i=0
    j=1
    while j < len(data['columnname']):    
        j=data['columnname'][i+1] - data['columnname'][i]    
        i+=1 #Next value of column. 
        j+=1 #Next value new column.    
        print(j)
```

Comment: _Are there any ways to achieve this?_ Probably, yes.

Comment: Can you tell me please how to implement that?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly, which part are you struggling with?

Comment: actually I don't know exactly how to code it for that my code is not complete and correct.

Comment: That's still vague, we need something specific.

Comment: I have posted the code but it is not working the way I want

Comment: _but it is not working the way I want_ We know that, otherwise you wouldn't be here! **Please make an effort.**

Comment: Hey! Welcome to stackoverflow! Please have a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as this is a crucial step towards your solution! What me and @AMC are confused about is _exactly_ what your desired output is. I do not understand what `NewColumn(c1.1)` means and the meaning of `p1` and `p2` are also lost on me.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? it finds the difference between the rows of a particular column using the [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method and assigns it to a new column. 
Note that I am using the data from Dave.

```
df['New Column'] = df.a.sub(df.a.shift()).fillna(0)

    a   b   c   New Column
0   1   1   1   0.0
1   2   1   4   1.0
2   3   2   9   1.0
3   4   3   16  1.0
4   5   5   25  1.0
5   6   8   36  1.0
```

For multiple columns, this may suffice:

```
M = df.diff().fillna(0).add_suffix('_1')

#concatenate along the columns axis

pd.concat([df,M], axis = 1)

    a   b   c   a_1 b_1 c_1
0   1   1   1   0.0 0.0 0.0
1   2   1   4   1.0 0.0 3.0
2   3   2   9   1.0 1.0 5.0
3   4   3   16  1.0 1.0 7.0
4   5   5   25  1.0 2.0 9.0
5   6   8   36  1.0 3.0 11.0
```

Comment: I want to do all this for my dataset whose shape is (30000,300). I can't do it manually for all. So I want Automatically create a new column with its name. You did exactly what I want. I want to do that for all the columns I have.

Comment: made some changes. have a look

Comment: It Gives error: out_arr[res_indexer] = arr[res_indexer] - arr[lag_indexer]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Are your data types in ur original DataFrame strings?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its work. I need one more favor if you can.

Comment: Go ahead. If I can’t someone else will

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60357798/i-want-to-use-fillna-mean-to-fill-the-missing-value-i-want-to-do-that-according

Answer (score 0):

You want the `diff` function:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html

```
df
   a  b   c
0  1  1   1
1  2  1   4
2  3  2   9
3  4  3  16
4  5  5  25
5  6  8  36
```

```
df.diff()
     a    b     c
0  NaN  NaN   NaN
1  1.0  0.0   3.0
2  1.0  1.0   5.0
3  1.0  1.0   7.0
4  1.0  2.0   9.0
5  1.0  3.0  11.0
```

Comment: Yes, i want to use diff function. But I want to iterate all rows and columns and insert the difference value in a new column and name it as a column from I have diff value. You can the above I have shown the output I want