# I want to use fillna Mean to fill the missing value. I want to do that according to product Id

Tags: python, pandas

```
product_ID Prodcut_Price   Product_monthly_sale
   1           24                2000.00
   1           Nan               2500.00    
   1           26                Nan
   1           28                2700.00
   2           25                2400.00
   2           Nan               Nan
   2           27                2600.00
```

I want to fill the nan value of product_price column and product_sale column based on product_id

Comment: Provide ur expected output. Also state what u have tried

Comment: maybe first you can do `df.groupby('product_id').mean()` and store it temporary. And then iterate over the dataframe, and when you encounter Nan, get the value from the temporary dataframe.

Comment: I want NAN value is Replace by using Fillna(median or mean) but based on product_id

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.** See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Also, how is this not a duplicate of this previous question of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60302731/i-want-to-fill-the-nan-value-with-mean-fillna-based-on-product-id-when-i-chan Why wouldn't you edit that question instead?

Comment: @AMC yes I did the research but the code I applied is not working. It takes time to execute but the result is the same. The earlier post was not good. So, I again post it. I am not aware much about StackOverflow. Now, I understand a few things. I have send code when I cannot resolve my problem.

Comment: @ankitgupta _but the code I applied is not working_ What code, where is the code? We need a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC df = df[['product_ID']].join(df.groupby("product_ID")
        .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())))                   This is the Code.

Comment: @ankitgupta That kind of information should be in your post, not a comment, and it's still nowhere near a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

**Create data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product_ID':[1,1,3,3,3], 
                   'Prodcut_Price':[1,np.nan,5,np.nan, 9],
                   'Product_monthly_sale':[1,np.nan,5,np.nan, 5]})
df
```

Result:

```
    product_ID  Prodcut_Price   Product_monthly_sale
0   1           1.0             1.0
1   1           NaN             NaN
2   3           5.0             5.0
3   3           NaN             NaN
4   3           9.0             5.0
```

**Fill nan with grouped means**

```
df = df[['product_ID']].join(df.groupby("product_ID")
        .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())))
df
```

Result:

```
    product_ID  Prodcut_Price   Product_monthly_sale
0   1           1.0             1.0
1   1           1.0             1.0
2   3           5.0             5.0
3   3           7.0             5.0
4   3           9.0             5.0
```

Comment: I want to do that for Dataset of shape(300000,600). It cannot be done manually.

Comment: You could use a for loop for that. See edited answer

Comment: Can you explain what it's doing basically?

Comment: @JonathandeMelker - I think bottleneck of code is calling lambda function.

Comment: @JonathandeMelker - Please not add my answer to  your solutions.

Comment: data[['product_id']].join(data.groupby("product_id").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))). I have execute this code. But when I check the null value its still show me null value why so??Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For improve performance avoid lambda function, rather use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for means per groups with [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df.fillna(df.groupby("product_ID").transform('mean'))
print (df)
   product_ID  Prodcut_Price  Product_monthly_sale
0           1           24.0                2000.0
1           1           26.0                2500.0
2           1           26.0                2400.0
3           1           28.0                2700.0
4           2           25.0                2400.0
5           2           26.0                2500.0
6           2           27.0                2600.0
```

Comment: I have used this code it takes time to execute the code but it has done nothing